# How to use _for_ in the dataframes in R programming

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to fit several models in R using the *for* loop.

The data I want to fit is the classical *Auto* data in a R pre-build package.
Let's discover the names of the columns of this dataframe:

```
names(Auto)
```

---

```
"mpg"          "cylinders"    "displacement" "horsepower"   "weight"       "acceleration" "year"        
"origin"       "name"
```

I want to fit the all these predictors one by one with the target 'mpg'.

Instead of doing:

> autotest1 = lm(mpg~cylinders, data=Auto)
>
> autotest2 = lm(mpg~displacement, data=Auto)
>
> autotest3 = lm(mpg~horsepower, data=Auto)
>
> autotest4 = lm(mpg~weight, data=Auto)
>
> autotest5 = lm(mpg~acceleration, data=Auto)
>
> autotest6 = lm(mpg~year, data=Auto)
>
> autotest7 = lm(mpg~origin, data=Auto)

I'm trying to use the *for* loop:

```
for (var in names(Auto))
{

  cat(lm(mpg~var, data=Auto))
```

### }

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = mpg ~ var, data = Auto, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'var')
```

I'm also trying Auto[i] with the index i being the columns of *Auto* dataframe without any success. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 4):

We can create a formula object with `paste`

```
for(var in names(Auto)) print(lm(paste('mpg ~', var), data = Auto))
```

Or with `reformulate`

```
for(var in names(Auto)) print(lm(reformulate(var, 'mpg'), data = Auto))
```

Comment: Using the paste methdo, I had the following output: Error in cat(lm(paste("mpg ~", var), data = Auto)) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped
2: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  problem with term 1 in model.matrix: no columns are assigned

Comment: @user26832 what is the output

Comment: The second one: Error in cat(lm(reformulate(var, "mpg"), data = Auto)) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped
2: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  problem with term 1 in model.matrix: no columns are assigned

Comment: @user26832 I would use `print` instead of `cat`

Comment: strange it didn't work. I think I ask another question or edit this one again. Thank you

Comment: @user26832 For me, it is working.  I used `Auto <- mtcars`

Comment: Please see the edit of my question, I tried with the print function as well, but it didn't work either

Comment: I made another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364671/strange-for-loop-behavior-on-r-programming

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be something like:

```
Auto <- mtcars
Auto$Var <- 1

Temp <- list()

for (i in 2:c(length(names(Auto))-1)) {

  print(names(Auto)[i])

  Auto$Var <- Auto[,i]

  ModelTemp <- lm(mpg~Var, data=Auto)
  Temp[[i-1]] <- ModelTemp
}
```